# Looking for an Android chart library with clickable items

Tags: android, charts

I'm looking for a (possibly free...) Android library that dynamically draws graph and permits to click on an item to show a sub-item.
Do you know any library with these features?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078479/what-android-3rd-party-libraries-are-there) question too. If you can't find it on that list add it once you've found what you are looking for.

Comment: AChartEngine currently support clickable items.

Answer (score 0):

You will find some discussion on this topic with good looking links in this post here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android

Comment: I had already seen it, but none of them supports, i think, clickable items ... this is why i asked help.

Comment: oh sorry. first read clickable but then in my search forgot about them. sorry. as well can't find anything. maybe you have to take one of those libs and add the click functionality yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webview with JAVASCRIPT based charting scripts to draw charts. you will easily find JS for graphics for charting. if other library seems not supportive/easy to find use this method.

OR

One Charting Library at [openintents.org](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/339)

-thanks